# How to intercept a Url to dynamically change the routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am looking to do something like:

For categories where the Controller will be `CategoryController`

```
www.mysite.com/some-category
www.mysite.com/some-category/sub-category
www.mysite.com/some-category/sub-category/another //This could go on ..
```

The problem is that: `www.mysite.com/some-product` needs to point to a `ProductController`. Normally this would map to the same controller.

So, how can I intercept the routing so I can check if the parameter is a Category or Product and route accordingly.

I am trying to avoid having something like `www.mysite.com/category/some-category` or `www.mysite.com/product/some-product` as I feel it will perform better on the SEO side. When I can intercept the routing, I'll forward to a product / category based on some rules that look at slugs for each etc.

Comment: How do you expect to distinguish between a product and a category? By the appended `-category` and `-product` at the end?

Comment: No, I'll do a cache look up to see if that data matches a product or category (I don't need the logic for this, just need to know where to put it). The final result won't have -product or -category.

Comment: I won't be able to do this via regex, I'll need to look in my `categoryService` and see if the string matches a slug or category tree structure and redirect accordingly. The same would happen with a `productService` if the category came back as null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom route to serve this purpose:

```
public class CategoriesRoute: Route
{
    public CategoriesRoute()
        : base("{*categories}", new MvcRouteHandler())
    {
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (rd == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string categories = rd.Values["categories"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(categories) || !categories.StartsWith("some-", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            // The url doesn't start with some- as per our requirement =>
            // we have no match for this route
            return null;
        }

        string[] parts = categories.Split('/');

        // for each of the parts go hit your categoryService to determine whether
        // this is a category slug or something else and return accordingly
       if (!AreValidCategories(parts)) 
       {
           // The AreValidCategories custom method indicated that the route contained
           // some parts which are not categories => we have no match for this route
           return null;
       }

        // At this stage we know that all the parts of the url are valid categories =>
        // we have a match for this route and we can pass the categories to the action
        rd.Values["controller"] = "Category";
        rd.Values["action"] = "Index";
        rd.Values["categories"] = parts;

        return rd;
    }
}
```

that will be registered like that:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add("CategoriesRoute", new CategoriesRoute());

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and then you can have the corresponding controller:

```
public class CategoryController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string[] categories)
    {
        ... The categories action argument will contain a list of the provided categories
            in the url
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks Darin. I'll have a go with it shortly.

Comment: Thanks again, the custom route is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is this likely have any impact on a form posting back? I'm trying to post a view that I've hit using this route and it's not posting to the controller.

Comment: No, there's no impact on the HTTP verb used. As long as you follow the correct url pattern it should work with any verb.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I assumed as much.

Comment: Any chance you could take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642628/html-actionlink-returning-a-parameterised-hyperlink as this custom route appears to break the functionality of `@Html.ActionLink`