# @Html.ActionLink returning a parameterised hyperlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am calling:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", new {area="FrontEnd"})
```

expecting

```
www.example.com/Account/Register
```

but I'm getting

```
http://www.example.com/?action=Register&controller=Account&area=FrontEnd
```

I'm a little confused as to why this happening, what can I do to resolve this?

**Edit**

When I remove the area parameter at the end, it builds the link correctly but to my admin section instead of `FrontEnd`.

**Edit**

I've isolated it to a custom route I have setup:

```
routes.Add("CategoriesRoute", new CategoriesRoute()); //This is breaking ActionLink.

routes.MapRoute("Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "FrontEnd", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "CC.Web.Areas.FrontEnd.Controllers" }
    );
```

This is the custom route.

```
public class CategoriesRoute : Route
{
    public CategoriesRoute()
        : base("{*categories}", new MvcRouteHandler())
    {
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (rd == null)
            return null;

        string categories = rd.Values["categories"] as string;
        if (categories.IsEmpty())
            return null;

        string[] parts = categories.Split('/');
        if (not a category) //pseudo code
            return null;

        rd.Values["controller"] = "Category";
        rd.Values["action"] = "Index";
        rd.Values["area"] = "FrontEnd";
        rd.DataTokens.Add("namespaces", new string[] { "CC.Web.Areas.FrontEnd.Controllers" });
        rd.Values["categoryString"] = "/" + categories; //Required to get exact match on the cache.

        return rd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below. I think you're missing an attribute `null` at the end

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", new {area="FrontEnd"}, null)
```

Comment: Please see my comment against the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `null` for the 5th parameter (html attributes)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", new {area="FrontEnd"}, null)
```

Comment: I've tried that but it results in the same. One thing to note, I have an `Account` controller in both Areas. Could that be causing the problem as it doesn't know which one to resolve to? Can I specify a namespace from the `ActionLink` to sort that if so?

Comment: You need to post your route definitions - I suspect that where the issue is

Comment: I've updated my OP. It's to do with a custom route but I'm not sure why. I thought returning null on these methods would cause it to skip and therefore not cause issues.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your trying to do with your custom route. What happens if you just comment out `routes.Add("CategoriesRoute" ...`?

Comment: If I comment it out, it works. The custom route is off the back of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572712/how-to-intercept-a-url-to-dynamically-change-the-routing where I am basically trying to get an unlimited amount of params and if it's a category, send it to the category controller else fall back to the Default route.

Comment: I suspect I'll have to use `RouteLink` to get around this though :(